# How to see which indices of an input effected an index of output

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I want to test my neural network.

For example, given: an input tensor `input`, a `nn.module` with some submodules `module`, an output tensor `output`,

I want to find which indices of `input` effected the index (1,2) of `output`

More specifically, given:

- Two input matrix of size (12, 12),
- Operation is `matmul`
- Queried index of the output matrix is: (0,0)

the expected output is:

```
InputMatrix1: (0,0), (0, 1), ..., (0, 11)

InputMatrix2: (0,0), (1, 0), ..., (11, 0)
```

Maybe visualization is okay.

Is there any method or libraries that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. You want to look at the non-zeros entries of the `grad` of `InputMatrix1` and `InputMatrix2` w.r.t the `(0,0)` element of the product:

```py
x = torch.rand((12, 12), requires_grad=True)  # explicitly asking for gradient for this tensor
y = torch.rand((12, 12), requires_grad=True)  # explicitly asking for gradient for this tensor
# compute the product using @ operator:
out = x @ y
# use back propagation to compute the gradient w.r.t out[0, 0]:
out[0,0].backward()
```

Inspect the non-zero elements of the inputs' gradients yield, as expected:

```py
In []: x.grad.nonzero()
```

> ```
> tensor([[ 0,  0],
>         [ 0,  1],
>         [ 0,  2],
>         [ 0,  3],
>         [ 0,  4],
>         [ 0,  5],
>         [ 0,  6],
>         [ 0,  7],
>         [ 0,  8],
>         [ 0,  9],
>         [ 0, 10],
>         [ 0, 11]])
> ```

```py
In []: y.grad.nonzero()
```

> ```
> tensor([[ 0,  0],
>         [ 1,  0],
>         [ 2,  0],
>         [ 3,  0],
>         [ 4,  0],
>         [ 5,  0],
>         [ 6,  0],
>         [ 7,  0],
>         [ 8,  0],
>         [ 9,  0],
>         [10,  0],
>         [11,  0]])
> ```

Comment: Combining this answer with `unittest` module, saved me a thousand years of misery debugging my neural network. Compare `result = x.grad.nonzero().tolist()` with your expected indices using `unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual(result, expected)`.